# Cannot deploy the program to devnet with anchor

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, anchor-solana

First, I tried with deploying on localhost with `anchor deploy` it works fine. But then I changed the cluster to devnet, changed `Anchor.toml` and `lib.rs` file with the address I got after `anchor build`. Then tried with `anchor deploy --provider.cluster devnet`

Changed the solana cluster also `solana config set --url https://api.devnet.solana.com`, then `solana program deploy /target/deploy/voter.so`. Still getting the error for both of the methods.

```
Deploying workspace: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: /home/XXXXXX/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "voter"...
Program path: /home/<user>/workspace/voter/target/deploy/voter.so...
Error: Account xxxx is not an upgradeable program or already in use
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if devnet is up and running with: https://status.solana.com

Then check if you have SOL: solana balance

^Usually it's one of those two!

I hope this helps!

Comment: I checked both, devnet is up and running, I have 5 SOL in devnet to test, so that shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives the info: `Error: Account xxxx is not an upgradeable program or already in use`

Check the address you're trying to deploy to.  You may need to change the program address to a new one if it's already being used by another program or user.

Comment: tried checking `target/deploy/voter-keypair.json` for address. Changed both Anchor.toml and lib.rs but still not able to get it