# having issues with deploying smart contract on solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-cli, solana-program-library

Anytime I try to deploy a contract on Solana I am always getting these issues.

```bash
Deploying workspace: https://api.devnet.solana.com

Upgrade authority: /Users/*****/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program ...

Program path: /Users/*****/*****/target/deploy/shii.so...

Error: Account ********** is not an upgradeable program or already in use

There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811084/cannot-deploy-the-program-to-devnet-with-anchor

Comment: I did all required in the question also asked, but still same issues and no solution to it